# Android Studio PieChart convert String/float to Integer - Toast

Tags: android, android-studio, integer, pie-chart, converters

I want to make PieChart and when you will press on the your chosen field on PieChart, then you will see Value of Chart (integer 15.. ect.)

I have problem with **Toast.maketext** when show value of "*counter*" show value 15.0 insted only 15. I want to have number without .0 at the end. 
When I was trying this option below (convert)the app was stopped working:

- int x = Integer.parseInt(counter);
- int x = Integer.valueOf(counter)
- try{ x = Integer.parseInt(counter)}
  catch(NumberFormat Exception nfe){}

My code:

```
pieChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: Value select from chart.");
            Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: " + e.toString());
            Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: " + h.toString());


            int pos1 = e.toString().indexOf("y: ");
            String counter = e.toString().substring(pos1 + 3);

            for(int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++){
                if(yData[i] == Float.parseFloat(counter)){
                    pos1 = i;
                    break;
                }

            }
                    String days = xData[pos1];
                    /*
                       1.)  int x = Integer.parseInt(counter);
                    2.) int x = Integer.valueOf(counter)
                     3.)try{ x = Integer.parseInt(counter)}
                    catch(NumberFormat Exception nfe){}
                    */

            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,  days+ " Day" + "counter" + x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,  days+ " Day" + "counter" + counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //add counter to Toast if you want to show counter
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```

Thank you for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

System.out.print(String.format("%1.0f", counter));

```
        Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,  days+ " Day" + "counter" + String.format("%1.0f", counter), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Not working, get text on phone emulator : Unfortunately PicChart has stooped working.

Answer (score 0):

For now I was solving like that:

```
Log.d(TAG, "onValueSelected: counter num " +counter);
            for(int i = 0; i < yData.length; i++){
                if(yData[i] == Float.parseFloat(counter)){
                    pos1 = i;
                    break;
                }

            }
            String days = xData[pos1];

            switch (pos1) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, days + " Day " + "\n" + "Numbers " +numberBad, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, days + " Day " + "\n" + "Numbers " +numberGod, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, days + " Day " + "\n" + "Numbers " +numberNor, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```